# Efficient way to prevent CPU from idling

Tags: python, swift, xcode, macos, sleep

My Mid-2014 Macbook Pro has a strange issue. It shuts off at seemingly random points, the issue is [detailed here by another user](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8115237).

It seems to be an issue where the CPU core becomes unstable because the voltage drops too low. The only way that I have found that prevents the issue 100% of the time is the following script

```
from time import sleep

while True:
  sleep(0.00002)
```

This works but it uses 15-20% CPU, not a big issue but I was wondering if there's a more efficient way to do it.

[image: CPU Usage]

I tried to doing a similar thing in Swift:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
  while true {
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.00002)
  }
}
```

It uses less CPU (3-5%) and the system seems to run a little bit more stable but it still occasionally shuts off.

Any ideas of other approaches I can try?

Comment: Have you seen [this advice](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/help-updated-to-macos-10-12-4-mbp-randomly-shuts-off.2039446/page-4#post-25605293), which is base on [this comment on SE](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/295525)?

Comment: No I haven't seen that. I will give it a try over the weekend. Thanks!!